# Arduino hardware interrupt reliability issue

Tags: arduino, external, interrupt

This may seem like a foolish problem and maybe its description is not the best I could have devised.

I am making a velocity sensor that uses two IR beams to calculate velocity based on the time it takes to break both beams.

I have two testing methods.

1. My hand (5-10 m/s)
2. A high speed cannon (30-60 m/s).

I have ruled out that it's a problem with the signal from the IR beams with an oscilloscope, when the code fails/works the data is identical on the scope.

My problem is that my code works when I use my hand, but still irregularly fails, while it fails more often at high speed. All the conditions are the same in both scenarios. What could be the issue?

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

const int rs = 9, en = 8, d4 = 7, d5 = 6, d6 = 5, d7 = 4;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

File root;
int fileNo = 0;
String currentFileName;
const int CS = 10;
const byte interruptPinStart = 2;
const byte interruptPinFinish = 3;

volatile unsigned long int startTimeMillis = 0;
volatile unsigned long int stopTimeMillis = 0;
volatile unsigned long int startTimeMicros = 0;
volatile unsigned long int stopTimeMicros = 0;
volatile unsigned long int microsDifference = 0;
volatile unsigned long int millisDifference = 0;

int launchNo = 0;
float currentVelocity = 0;
volatile boolean started = false;
String inputString = "";       
boolean stringComplete = false;  
const int txLed1 = 14;
const int statusLed1 = 15;
const int statusLed2 = 16;
volatile boolean triggerDone = false;
float velocity = 0;
String temp;
unsigned long int lockout = 0;
boolean lockedOut = false;
boolean fileFail = false;
int testNo = 0;

void setup() {
  inputString.reserve(200);
  pinMode(statusLed1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(statusLed2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(txLed1, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; 
  }
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(interruptPinStart, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPinStart), startTrigger, RISING);
  pinMode(interruptPinFinish, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPinFinish), stopTrigger, RISING);
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if (!SD.begin(CS)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");
  root = SD.open("/");
  newDirectory(root);
  Serial.println("done!");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print(currentFileName);
  tone(txLed1, 38000);
}

void loop() {
  int millsDiff = millis() - stopTimeMillis;
  if (triggerDone) {
    lockedOut = true;
    Serial.print("Micros Diffrence: ");
    Serial.println(microsDifference);
    Serial.print("Millis Difference: ");
    Serial.println(millisDifference);
    float millDiff = (float) millisDifference;
    float microDiff = (float) microsDifference;
    if (microDiff > 0) {
      velocity = (float) 0.09 / (microDiff/1000000);
      testNo++;
      temp = String(launchNo) + "%" + String(microsDifference) + "%" + String(velocity);
      if (velocity > 10.0) {
        root = SD.open(currentFileName, FILE_WRITE);
        if (root) {
          root.println(temp);
          root.close();
          Serial.println(temp);
          launchNo++;
        } else {
          Serial.println("error opening file, " + currentFileName);
          fileFail = true;
        }
      }
      if (fileFail) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("File Error");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Vel " + String(launchNo) + ": " + String(velocity) + " m/s");
        fileFail = false;
      } else {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Test Number: " + String(testNo));
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Vel " + String(launchNo) + ": " + String(velocity) + " m/s");
      }
    } 
    triggerDone = false;
    Serial.println("Test Number: " + String(testNo));
  }
  if (digitalRead(interruptPinStart) == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(statusLed1, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(statusLed1, LOW);
  }
  if (digitalRead(interruptPinFinish) == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(statusLed2, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(statusLed2, LOW);
  }
}

void startTrigger() {
  startTimeMicros = micros();
  startTimeMillis = millis();
  volatile int diff1 = startTimeMicros - startTimeMillis;
  volatile int diff2 = startTimeMillis - stopTimeMillis;
  if (diff2 > 200) {
    if (started == false || diff1 > 1000) {
      started = true;
      triggerDone = false;
    }
  }
}

void stopTrigger() {
  stopTimeMicros = micros();
  stopTimeMillis = millis();
  microsDifference = stopTimeMicros - startTimeMicros;
  millisDifference = stopTimeMillis - startTimeMillis;
  if ((millisDifference > 0  && millisDifference < 800) && started) {
    microsDifference = stopTimeMicros - startTimeMicros;
    millisDifference = stopTimeMillis - startTimeMillis;
    started = false;
    triggerDone = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's `startTimeMicros - startTimeMillis` supposed to do? Why do you use the milliseconds at all?

Comment: How long is the beam broken when the fast object passes through?  It is possible that it's just so brief that it doesn't reliably trigger the interrupt?  Is it possible that the second beam is broken while the first interrupt is still running?

Comment: Could the SD Card library be disabling interrupts or suchlike?

Comment: I think it might have just been the SD card library messing with the interrupts. Thanks @Kingsley